# Vue Lazy Load image error before loading data

Tags: vue.js, lazy-loading

I'm using VueLazyLoad in my Vuejs app. I send a request to get a product information, such as name & image. I use lazyload like this:

```
<img v-lazy="product.img"/>
```

But here's the problem, at first, product information has not been loaded and `product.img` is `null`, so VueLazyLoad uses the error image, then product info is fetched and it jumps up on img tag.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried not rendering this DOM element at all unless product.img exists? i.e. `<img v-if="product.img" v-lazy="product.img"/>`

Comment: @Maylor I want to show loading image unless `product.img` is completely loaded.